# Kotlin function declaration with dot, what does it mean?

Tags: kotlin

```
abstract class Children : Parent {
    
    fun create(
        param1 : String,
        param2 : String,
        param3 : String

    ): (MyWork) -> Unit = 
        createWork(param1, param2 + param3)

    fun Parent.createWork(
        param1 : String,
        param2 : String
    ): (MyWork) -> Unit = 
        createWork(
            param1 + param2
        )


    private fun Parent.createWork(
        param1 : String
    ): (MyWork) -> Unit = { work: MyWork ->
        work.name = param1
    }
}
```

I am recently learning Kotlin for one of my project, I encouter these piece of code, this is first time I see Kotlin function with a dot there `Parent.createWork`, I checked the `Parent` interface, there is no such function `createWork`, what does it mean here actually? I have searched this, but only found something so-called "dot operator", but it is not the same thing. Can anyone point me to the right place?

Comment: Looks like an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) for the class `Parent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a Kotlin **extension function** which allows you to add new class functionality without inheritance. You can read more about them in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions).